# How to perform arrays of arrays using list method of php?

Tags: php

Code is as follows:-

```
  $student=array(
  "HINDI"=>array("marks"=>"96","grade"=>"1st"),
  "ENGLISH"=>array("marks"=>"92","grade"=>"1st")
   );
```

In above code I want to get the output like using php `list()` method

**subject =hindi marks=96 grade=1st
subject =english marks=94 grade=1st**

Thank you :)

Comment: Didn't you even tried with simple loop?

Comment: Some of the information that you need are keys of an array, not values. You won't be able to do that using **only** `list()`.

Comment: There is a thing called a [manual](http://php.net/docs.php) It is designed to help people who dont yet know how to program in PHP to become better at programming in PHP. It is writen in many languages. See [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) specifically to help with this problem

Comment: I already have done this but On that time i only use foreach loop twice but now I want to know how to make it through list. Thank you...

Comment: Try something, if it does not work, show us what you tried, we are more than willing to help. BUT SO **is not a free coding service**. You have to show some effort first

Comment: I edited my answer and solved the problem. I will be grateful if the guys who downvoted me could undo that.

Comment: ok I give my code which implement with foreach loop.

Comment: foreach($student as $subject=>$sub)
{echo "$subject ";
 foreach($sub as $marks=>$number)
 {
  echo "$marks = "," $number ";
 }
 echo "<br/>";
}

Comment: Well, this is already the proper way of doing that, it's not worth trying to optimize it. This is the exact answer I posted.

Comment: thanks I tried it with myself through list. Thanks for your kind help...

Comment: @sandeep_1994: no problem! But please mark the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without a list just by using `foreach` like

```
 $student=array(
  "HINDI"=>array("marks"=>"96","grade"=>"1st"),
  "ENGLISH"=>array("marks"=>"92","grade"=>"1st")
   );

   foreach ($student as $subject => $student)
   {
        echo "subject=".$subject." marks=".$student['marks']." grade=".$student['grade']." "; // add strtolower to get lower char 
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't retrieve keys using list, but you can get sub arrays like this:

```
<?php

  list($a, list($aa, $ab, $ac)) = array(0, array(1, 2, 3));

  echo $a;
  echo '<br>';

  echo $aa;
  echo '<br>';

  echo $ab;
  echo '<br>';

  echo $ac;
  echo '<br>';

?>
```

But if you forget about list(), you can do this and get the output you asked for:

```
<?php

$students=array(
  "HINDI"=>array("marks"=>"96","grade"=>"1st"),
  "ENGLISH"=>array("marks"=>"92","grade"=>"1st")
   );

   $output = '';
   foreach($students as $name => $student)
   {
     $output .= ' subject='.$name;
     foreach($student as $key => $value)
     $output .= ' '.$key.'='.$value;
   }

   echo $output;

?>
```